# How to compare a word from a ArrayList to a word in a file?

Tags: java, arraylist

The program I'm creating is a 'spell check' kind of program but have been specifically told to have the dictionary words in a `ArrayList` and the file we are comparing the words in to be a .txt file.

For the life of me I can not figure out how to compare them.

This is what I've gotten so far(it doesn't have the compare loop since none of them even came close to working).

```
package testDelimeter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    ArrayList<String> dict = new ArrayList<String>();


    File  inFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\workspace1\\testDelimeter\\src\\testDelimeter\\" + "dict" + ".txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inFile);

    File  text = new File("C:\\Users\\Ceri\\workspace1\\testDelimeter\\src\\testDelimeter\\" + "text" + ".txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(text);


    while(in.hasNext()){
        dict.add(in.next());
    }


}


}
```

Guidance more than anything would be brilliant!

Comment: How about reading the words one by one from the text one, and then looping over the arraylist and comparing with each of its content words?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, this should work:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> dictionary = createDictionaryFromFile("C:\\path\\to\\dictionary\\dictionary.txt");

        Scanner fileToCheck = new Scanner("C:\\path\\to\\file");
        while (fileToCheck.hasNext()) {
            String wordToCheck = fileToCheck.next();
            if (!dictionary.contains(wordToCheck.toLowerCase())) {
                System.out.println("Misspelled word: " + wordToCheck);
            }
        }
    }

    private static ArrayList<String> createDictionaryFromFile(String path) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(path);
        ArrayList<String> dictionary = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            dictionary.add(scanner.next().toLowerCase());
        }
        return dictionary;
    }
}
```

Also ArrayList's contains operation is not very efficient. If you change ArrayList to Set it will be much more efficient.

Comment: both Fame and fame are correct as per spelling is concern. The ArrayList.contains() will return false although..

Comment: Yes, you are right. I've added fix. Though I thought question was about principle of how to do it. There are many details which should be improved for correct spell checking.